# Serving djangocms project from subfolder

Tags: django, nginx, django-cms

My site is currently running with: nginx, uwsgi, django (with djangocms).

I need to move everything under a subfolder /abc

nginx

```
location /abc {
    uwsgi_pass rak;
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /abc;
}
```

The site works well but when I try to load any cms page I get 404 or the "Create page" wizard.

All the other apps are correctly served under the /abc/ subfolder even when attached to the cms via apphook.
The url reverse works good and the admin site is ok.

Am I missing something?